# How to setup exactly same two 3d viewport

Tags: settings, viewport, blender

First of all, sorry for my english

I have two 3d viewport, the first one for editing and the other for live render. The problem is i need to orbit again so they have same viewing angle. So is there any other way to do it more easily?

Comment: Sorry, it should be on sub blender

Comment: Ask this here [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have both 3D viewports showing the camera view <kbd>numpad 0</kbd> you can enable *Lock Camera to View* and both viewports will show the same movement. You can find the lock to view option in the [View panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#view-panel) in the properties region <kbd>N</kbd>. You only need to lock the one viewport that you will be using to move around in.

[image: lock camera to view]

As this will actually move the location of the camera, you may want to have a second camera to use for this and switch the active camera between your viewport and rendering camera in the [scene properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/properties.html).